# Xcode 6.3 crashes when I rename the project

Tags: ios, xcode, rename

Yesterday I updated Xcode to the 6.3 version since my iPhone has the 8.3 software version and Xcode wanted the latest version to run the app. So everything updated now but Xcode cant't rename the project anymore.

If I duplicated the project then open it and type e new name in Identity and Type name field it crashes systematically.

I've tried to change the bundle name first and I've made a step over but it renames the project name without the extension (.xcodeproj). I added it by hand but when I open the project again it returns errors and does not let me run the project nor in the simulator or in the device.

Anyone who experiments the issue?
Is there another way to rename the project?

Comment: I confirm the same problem in Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: Raised a bug 20707964.

Comment: OH NO my project?? same thing. And all my snapshots disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is a known bug with xcode 6.3.1 Renaming manually here and there is simply a risk and time-consuming.
There's a more effective way of doing it via Command-line with just 3 statements. Read on.

Two Solutions exist:

1- Upgrade to Xcode 6.3.2 GM seed or later

2- Replace by command-line - it’s fast & furious..urm effective!! *Mention not*

#### /// Install Ack. For info on Ack, see: http://beyondgrep.com/why-ack/

```
$ brew install rename ack
```

#### /// Two Commands to execute to do renaming - one for File names & 2nd for 'leterals' inside files

```
$ find . -name 'OldProjectName*' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -S 'OldProjectName' 'NewProjectName'

$ ack --literal --files-with-matches 'OldProjectName' | xargs sed -i '' 's/OldProjectName/NewProjectName/g'
```

#### /// Check to see if all renaming was a success. The following command indicates a success IF & ONLY IF no result is output

```
$ ack --literal 'OldProjectName'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make "New Scheme" in a place where you can select the device. Then save it and the project should be run on the device as well as on the simulator.

The following screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]