# Best way to rename an app in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time I select the `Target`(the app), then change the app's name in `Identity and Type`, Xcode crashes. Is there a good way to change the name of an existing app? Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a bug of Xcode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670810/xcode-6-3-crashes-when-i-rename-the-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into a solution for this a few days ago, and unfortunately I think there's no straightforward way to rename a project. What I ended up doing, because I hadn't done much in the project, was to create a new project with the correct name and then copy the files I needed, such as the storyboards, class files, etc.